# How to apply edit an existing excel file Laravel-Excel

Tags: php, excel, laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-excel

I'm using the **[Laravel-Excel](https://github.com/SpartnerNL/Laravel-Excel)** package, and I am trying to make changes to an existing excel file.

But I don't know how to proceed, can someone enlighten me, and I can't find something in the documentation, If you have any idea or solution to my problem.

**Some intel :**
I don't use any models, basically in input I have an excel file, then I have to apply modifications, But I don't know how to edit excel file.

Comment: So as I understand you are using a package, not using models and you want to save the changes after submitted? Assuming you know how to make the changes on the excel after imported, you can store your updated excel files into some folder in the storage inside the project and that must solve your problem

Comment: Hello, in the current time, I have the list of all changes, but i'm searching how to apply them and then store the file.

Comment: Hi, as I mentioned in the comment, you can create a folder inside storage and store them there with the changes made. If you want to see how to apply them, everything is mentioned in the package you are using

Comment: I think you didn't get. I'm not searching somewhere to store my excel file.
I want to do custom edit on excel file, the package mentions using models but I don't use model. That's why I'm asking.